# Show system files / Show git ignore in osx

Tags: macos, git

By default it is not possible to see .gitignore files in osx. What is command to reveal these files?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Open the terminal and type

- on OS X 10.8:

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
  ```
- on OS X 10.9:

  ```
  defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
  ```

Then you must relaunch finder:

```
killall Finder
```

Any file name in OS X prefixed with a '.' is considered "hidden".

Comment: This command will show all hidden files, is there a way to actually make the specific files always visible ?

Comment: See prodigitalson's answer.

Comment: So there is no way to make it global unfortunatelly, thanks @snarf

Comment: Check out [this post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115009/77639) on AskDifferent that has AppleScript for toggling hidden files. You can use Automator to create a service that runs that script and assign a keyboard shortcut to that service so you can quickly toggle on and off hidden files.

Comment: This command isn't working on Yosemite or El Capitan.This is the right answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29219426/1803863

Comment: Even after showing hidden files, if your are not able to found .gitignore file then simply in terminal type `touch .gitignore` in this directory. This will create new gitignore file.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what is the difference between the commands for OS X 10.8 and 10.9? they look exactly the same, am I missing something?

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu lower vs uppercase "F" in `com.apple.Finder`

Comment: You can also restart the finder by going to Apple -> Force quite -> Finder -> restart

Answer (score 83):

You can use the shortcut in Finder:

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

It will show the hidden files.
To hide the files again, use the same shortcut.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me (on catalina)

Comment: Thank you! This should be number 1 here.

Comment: Thank god for this, deffo should be number 1

Answer (score 54):

`⌘⇧.` will toggle the `AppleShowAllFiles` setting.

This key combo will work from open/save dialogue boxes in all apps, not just the finder. Use this and you’ll never be confused when on someone else’s Mac or a new Mac, and you can avoid mucking around with `defaults write`.

I use the nemonic of “use a dot to show a dot file” to remember it, because of hidden dot files in unix.

Comment: Much better because of "Use this and you’ll never be confused when on someone else’s Mac or a new Mac".

Answer (score 18):

if you just want to look at them you can always use the command line:

`ls -al path/to/dir`

If you want to always view **all** files from the finder you can do:

`defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles YES`

If you just want to view a .gitignore from the finder you can:

`chflags nohidden /path/to/dir/.gitignore`

But youll have to call that command on every `.gitignore` its not global.

Answer (score 16):

(more recent, for 10.10.2:)

The above commands didn't work for me. I'm using OSX Yosemite: 10.10.2.
This worked though:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true;
killall Finder;
```

Source:
http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/08/04/how-to-show-hidden-files-folders-finder-mac/

Comment: hey there thanks for the post.  If someone is trying to use this, then I had success using the following command line: "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true ; killall Finder".  Otherwise, it does not work.

Comment: Is there a way to show just the file starting by dot "." but not the system file?

Answer (score 9):

You can edit hidden file in terminal using this command

```
open -a TextEdit .gitignore
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to view a .gitignore from the console just type "nano .gitignore" in that directory. This command "nano" simply opens any textfile in nano console environment for viewing or editing

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197286/6813459), you can create an alias to easily show/hide the hidden files in Terminal. This is how I set it up (tested/working on macOS Mojave 10.14.1).

In my user directory I created a new file `.custom_aliases` and wrote this in:

```
# Show/hide files
alias showall='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true; killall Finder'
alias hideall='defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean false; killall Finder'
```

Next I opened `.bash-profile` (should also be in your user directory, if not just create it there) and added this to the top of the file:

```
# Load custom aliases
source ~/.custom_aliases
```

And that's it! Now whenever I need to view the hidden files I just type `showall` in Terminal and `hideall` when I'm done. You could also define the aliases directly in the `.bash_profile`, but I have some other stuff so I like to keep all the aliases together in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

**Show hide file and folder on MacOs Mojave 10.14.4**

> Apply at Terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -boolean true;
killall Finder;
```

Answer (score -4):

It's possible you might just not have a `.gitignore` file. If you don't have one, you can create it like this:

```
>touch ~/.gitignore
```

And then edit it however you'd like. Git will automatically check this file, without any additional configuration!