# Purge hidden storage on Github Desktop OSX?

Tags: git, macos, storage, github-for-mac

I have several folders of jpg files on my OSX laptop, cloned from a GitHub repository. The files I can see total less than 20GB, but my system tells me that they occupy 65+GB.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/65BFp.png]

Where are these hidden files? How can I purge them?

I should mention that there is only one branch in the repository.

(Also, I know that GitHub is not meant to be a place to store lots of image files. This repo is a component of a larger project.)

Comment: To clarify, you want to know how to remove the local copies of the image files, but retain them in the online "origin" repository?

Comment: The extra space could be from the Git history. Keep in mind that Git keeps a copy (or the information that it needs to revert to a copy) of every committed revision of the file.

Comment: What I want(ed) to do, @neontapir, was to retain them in the online "origin" repository (along with all their history) but only keep the most recent copy locally.

Comment: Thanks @zneak. I suspect that what I wanted to do is not possible?

Comment: @WillHanley, if you don’t care for history, you can look into shallow clones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Show system files / Show git ignore in osx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45019303/6309)", use in your Finder <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

That should show you the hidden folder `.git/`, which include all the history of the repo.
And for a repo of binaries (like jpeg images), and new version of an image might take quite a lot of place (poor diff, poor compression between each version)

> I wonder if there's any way I can purge this history from local storage? (I'd like to keep it in the cloud)

You would need to [download only the archive of the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8378458/6309) (meaning the content, without the history).
If you don't need to change and push back those modification, the archive would be enough.

If you need the history, a shallow clone (`git clone --depth 1`) that I [detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21217267/6309) ([or here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920956/6309)) is best to keep the downloaded data at a minimum.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I can see it now. I wonder if there's any way I can purge this history from local storage? (I'd like to keep it in the cloud).

Comment: @WillHanley I have edited my answer to address your comment/question.

Comment: Thanks. I want to continue to push modifications, so will try the shallow clone suggested by @zneak and described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352894/how-to-git-fetch-efficiently-from-a-shallow-clone).

Comment: @WillHanley OK. I have edited the answer to add the shallow option, with links to old answers of mine where I describe a shallow clone.

Answer (score 0):

I would try re-indexing your hdd and see if that accurately displays file sizes once its done.

Run the following in osx terminal:

```
    sudo mdutil -E /
```

Original article:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-wrong-hard-drive-data-usage-calculation-osx/