# Remote -v is not returning any information about the git repository

Tags: github, repository, push

relatively inexperienced git user here, but I have an issue where the command git remote -v is not returning any information about the git repository that I forked from GitHub. I have .git running in the folder and it is an exact replica of the one I have in my GitHub account. The original was forked from a coding school (the files contain practice problems). Right now I'm trying to push back to the repository but that isn't working either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does `git remote -v` show any error messages? Also, "*that isn't working either.*" -- any error messages? Also, what command did you use to *clone* repository locally?

Comment: When I initially tried to push back to the repository, it looked liked the files moved over but there was no evidence on the GitHub side (no changes, new time stamps, etc). I used git clone + the http address of the forked repository. Thanks!

Comment: no error messages from git remote -v, just started a new command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again and clone your fork with a `git clone https://github.com/<me>/<myfork>`

Then go into the `myfork` folder created by the `git clone`, and check that `git remote -v` does return the correct origin URL.

Comment: Thanks! I did this and but after asking for ls -a, I don't see a myfork folder. Hmm.

Comment: @ErinL Which OS are you using? Which shell? And which Git version?

Comment: I'm running Catalina, git version 2.24.3, terminal

Comment: sorry, zsh might be what you wanted to know, re: shell

Comment: @ErinL Can you activate "showing hidden files" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56057761/6309) and see if can find your cloned folder then?

Comment: Just tried - looked in new cloned folder and I don't see myfork!

Comment: @ErinL And in your original local fork (the one where `git remote -v` returns nothing) do you see a `.git` subfolder?

Comment: I do, yes - I have a git folder in both the folder that contains the forked project and the folder that it's in.

Comment: @ErinL and the folder that it's in"? there should be only one .git folder under your local cloned fork. Not `.git/.git`

Comment: Sorry, I think I might have misunderstood - I cloned the repository again, but did you want me to literally copy https://github.com/<me>/<myfork>? I just tried that in terminal but got an error message : zsh: parse error near `\n'

Comment: @ErinL You should cloned in a separate folder, outside of any existing local Git repository.

Comment: @ErinL I have an errand to make. I will be back in a few hours.

Comment: There's no git folder within the git folder. I just meant that I have git running one cd level up as well. I could get rid of it if it's unnecessary.

Comment: no problem, sorry this issue is so annoying!

Comment: What do you know, git remote -v is running now, on this new clone. VonC thanks for your patience and help. I will just copy files over and get rid of the old one.